# inonice not working properly in xen dom0

Tags: xen, io, vmstat, ionice

I have a Xen Dom0 (3.2) with a bunch of domUs (paravirt). DomU VBDs are on local LVM volumes. Now I want to get backups of the LVM volumes using snapshots. I use rsync ioniced to idle (ionice -c3).

I have verified that the rsync processes are really in idle mode and the `blkback` kernel threads are on best efford (-c2 -n4).

As I understand the IO scheduling system, the so configured rsync process should never be able to steal IO bandwidth from the `blkback` processes and therefor the impact on the domUs should be zero.

But that's not what I see. In the domUs `vmstat` shows up to 20% IO wait during rsync filelist operation and about 10% on rsync transferring data:

```
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
1  3    456  48468 103004 1550936    0    0    75   484 2112 1741  3  0 81 16
```

Without rsync running the IO wait is around 1%:

```
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
1  0    456  43876 105564 1553224    0    0    19   365 2063 1718  4  0 95  1
```

dom0 shows steady 11% IO wait on rsync filelist operation and 5% on data transfer:

```
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0  23536 220220  73256 558856    0    0  1471   239 5271  310  0  0 89 11
```

So, has anyone an idea about what's happening here? Is ionice simply broken or am I expecting the wrong effects?

Thanks for any hint.

tim

Answer (score 0):

What distribution you have in use?

What file system you have in use?

What I/O scheduler (CFQ, deadline, anticipatory, noop) you have in use?

During heavy file operations 0% I/O wait is not a reasonable thing to expect. There WILL be some I/O wait with rotational disks, no matter what. Some file systems reduce that effect a bit, sometimes tuning or changing I/O scheduler can help a bit, sometimes you'll just have to live with a little bit of I/O wait. Around 10-20% is not THAT much unless you notice that as a dramatic slowdown with your server. In case of dramatic slowdowns you might get hint about what's going on with tools like `btrace`, which shows individual I/O requests, their status and overall I/O scheduler / block device statistics.

Comment: This is Ubuntu on CFQ Scheduler. It's not that I'm expecting 0% IO wait. I'm expecting nearly 0 impact from idle-niced IOs on "best-effort"-niced IOs.

Comment: Sry, Kernel is: 2.6.24-24-xen #1 SMP Tue Jun 30 21:53:02 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux